# Dynamic mapping in Dozer and Camel

Tags: apache-camel, dozer

I am looking at implementing an integration scenario where I need to perform dynamic mapping from a source to a target, the issue is that the mapping should be fairly configurable and cannot be linked to fixed values.

I am using Camel as the integration framework and import a file (can have different data structure but we assume that it is a CSV file) then I need to map the data from the file to an internal format. I am looking at using Dozer and the XML mapping configuration to perform this mapping.

So what i though of doing is to load the file, unmarshal the CSV and then split the file and next I would like to map the HashMap(produced from the CSV unmarshal) in the camel body to another hashMap but change the values of the keys.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

```
<bean id="Debug" class="com.mycompany.camel.spring.DebugProcessor" />
<bean id="dozerConverterLoader"
    class="org.apache.camel.converter.dozer.DozerTypeConverterLoader" />

<bean id="DynamicMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>Mapping.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<camelContext trace="false"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:src?fileName=sample_data.csv&amp;noop=true" />
        <unmarshal>
            <csv delimiter="," skipHeaderRecord="true" useMaps="true" />
        </unmarshal>
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <bean ref="Debug" />
            <bean ref="DynamicMapper" />
            <bean ref="Debug" />
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The mapping file looks as follow (purely as an example, this will obviously expand with more field mappings)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <mapping>
        <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
        <class-b>java.util.HashMap</class-b>
        <field>
            <a key="overtimehours">this</a>
            <b key="OVT_HRS">TargetMap</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

However when i execute the camel route i keep on getting an exception "org.dozer.MappingException: Destination class must not be null"

What am i doing wrong? and any other suggestions are also welcome to achieve the dynamic mapping functionality.

Comment: you need to show the code of your dynamic mapper as that is the dozer code that fails. Also read the dozer doc what that error means in dozer-land.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can directly refer to the dozerBeanMapper class to invoke a particular mapping. You could use `<convertBodyTo type="Hashmap"/>` but since its already a HashMap I don't know if that would work. Could you put a wrapper around the hashmap for the target type and then use `<convertBodyTo type="newWrapperClass"/>` ?